# How to get a reference to current module's attributes in Python

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do would look like this in the command line:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> names = dir(mymodule)
```

How can I get a reference to all the names defined in `mymodule` from within `mymodule` itself?

Something like this:

```
# mymodule.py
names = dir(__thismodule__)
```

Comment: please also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281300/automatically-call-all-functions-matching-a-certain-pattern-in-python

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Just use globals()

> globals() — Return a dictionary
>   representing the current global symbol
>   table. This is always the dictionary
>   of the current module (inside a
>   function or method, this is the module
>   where it is defined, not the module
>   from which it is called).

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals

Comment: Is there any way to access the gloabals() of the calling module, instead of the defining module?

Comment: You may try getting caller's globals from the traceback module (http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html), but this is getting into dark magic territory. I don't know what you're trying to do, but you may want to rethink your design if you need that.

Comment: A classic case of "I need X (to get Y done) -> You don't need X you need Z". I do need X though! No offense, I just find this amusing, and the most voted answer gives me the answer I need :)

Comment: Important to note that the globals() can return wrong result as it depends on the context where being called. For example, if make a call from a class function, then it will return the global context linked to the class, not the current module context, which is significally different thing. Even if make a call from a free function it can return a different module global context, dependent on how the function has been imported.

Answer (score 212):

As previously mentioned, globals gives you a dictionary as opposed to dir() which gives you a list of the names defined in the module.  The way I typically see this done is like this:

```
import sys
dir(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Comment: I was going to add a comment that this wouldn't work for the '__main__' module (which is what the module run at the terminal is called) because that does not seem to be listed in sys.modules - but it does indeed work :)

Comment: However, it doesn't seem to work from ipdb (insert "import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()" into your file).

Comment: Excellent! This just allowed me to use the current module's docstring as a usage message - `sys.modules[__name__].__doc__`.

Comment: And to get super hacky. `operators.attrgetter('module.attribute')(sys.modules[__name__])` -- you know, if you do crazy things people tell you not to do like dynamically import packages from strings and then monkey patch those while not being within a class or anything...

Comment: "Excellent! This just allowed me to use..." `sys.modules[__name__].get_config = lambda: config` in my module's `init()` function to freeze the results once config changes (which are just global vars) have no meaning. I use this in my log_lib that has been improving for nearly 10 years.

Comment: For anyone reading comment by george: `sys.modules[__name__].__doc__` == `__doc__` as this is defined in the current namespace. Fetching the module object to access its own attributes is therefore not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

It might be late to answer, but I didn't found the correct answer for myself.
The most closest and precise solution (faster than `inspect.stack()`) in the python `3.7.x`:

```py
# search for first module in the stack
stack_frame = inspect.currentframe()
while stack_frame:
  print('***', stack_frame.f_code.co_name, stack_frame.f_code.co_filename, stack_frame.f_lineno)
  if stack_frame.f_code.co_name == '<module>':
    if stack_frame.f_code.co_filename != '<stdin>':
      caller_module = inspect.getmodule(stack_frame)
    else:
      # piped or interactive import
      caller_module = sys.modules['__main__']
    if not caller_module is None:
      #... do something here ...
    break
  stack_frame = stack_frame.f_back
```

**Pros**:

- Preciser than `globals()` method.
- Does not depend on the stack intermediate frames, which can be added for example, via hooking or by the 3dparty tools like `pytest`:

```
*** foo ... ..
*** boo ... ..
*** runtest c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\xonsh\pytest_plugin.py 58
*** pytest_runtest_call c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py 125
*** _multicall c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py 187
*** <lambda> c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py 86
*** _hookexec c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py 92
*** __call__ c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py 286
*** <lambda> c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py 201
*** from_call c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py 229
*** call_runtest_hook c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py 201
*** call_and_report c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py 176
*** runtestprotocol c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py 95
*** pytest_runtest_protocol c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py 80
*** _multicall c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py 187
*** <lambda> c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py 86
*** _hookexec c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py 92
*** __call__ c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py 286
*** pytest_runtestloop c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py 258
*** _multicall c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py 187
*** <lambda> c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py 86
*** _hookexec c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py 92
*** __call__ c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py 286
*** _main c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py 237
*** wrap_session c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py 193
*** pytest_cmdline_main c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py 230
*** _multicall c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py 187
*** <lambda> c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py 86
*** _hookexec c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py 92
*** __call__ c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py 286
*** main c:\python\x86\37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py 90
*** <module> c:\Python\x86\37\Scripts\pytest.exe\__main__.py 7
```

- Can handle python piped or interactive session.

**Cons:**

- A kind of much precise and can return modules registered in an executable like for the `pytest.exe` which might not what you want.
- `inspect.getmodule` still may return None on valid modules depending on hooking

I have an extension to the python:
[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path/57843421#57843421)

The extension having wrapper functions for that case:

```py
def tkl_get_stack_frame_module_by_offset(skip_stack_frames = 0, use_last_frame_on_out_of_stack = False):
  ...

def tkl_get_stack_frame_module_by_name(name = '<module>'):
  ...
```

You have to just initialize the extension properly:

```py
# portable import to the global space
sys.path.append(<path-to-tacklelib-module-directory>)
import tacklelib as tkl

tkl.tkl_init(tkl, global_config = {'log_import_module':os.environ.get('TACKLELIB_LOG_IMPORT_MODULE')})

# cleanup
del tkl # must be instead of `tkl = None`, otherwise the variable would be still persist
sys.path.pop()

# use `tkl_*` functions directly from here ...
```