# Automatically call all functions matching a certain pattern in python

Tags: python, automation

In python I have many functions likes the ones below. I would like to run all the functions whose name matches `setup_*` without having to explicitly call them from main. The order in which the functions are run is not important. How can I do this in python?

```
def setup_1():
    ....

def setup_2():
    ....

def setup_3():
    ...

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_*()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def setup_1():
    print('1')

def setup_2():
    print('2')

def setup_3():
    print('3')

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    for func in (val for key,val in vars().items()
                 if key.startswith('setup_')):
        func()
```

yields

```
# 1
# 3
# 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible solution:

```
import types

def setup_1():
    print "setup_1"

def setup_2():
    print "setup_2"

def setup_3():
    print "setup_3"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for name, member in globals().items():  # NB: not iteritems()
        if isinstance(member, types.FunctionType) and name.startswith("setup_"):
            member()
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not get function objects directly but must use eval, I am checking solution with vars() to get rid of eval:

```
     def setup_1():
        print('setup_1')

    def setup_2():
        print('setup_2')

    def setup_3():
        print('setup_3')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        [eval(func+'()') for func in dir() if func.startswith('setup_')]
```

Ok, here the version with vars():

```
def setup_1():
    print('setup_1')

def setup_2():
    print('setup_2')

def setup_3():
    print('setup_3')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    [vars()[func]() for func in dir() if func.startswith('setup_')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locals()`

```
L = locals()
for k in L:
    if hasattr(L[k], '__call__') and k.startswith('setup'):
        L[k]()
```

Of course you'll want to make sure that your function names don't appear elsewhere in locals.

In addition, you could also do something like this because functions are first class objects (note the function names are not strings):

```
setupfunctions = [setup_1, setup_2, setup_3, myotherfunciton]
for f in setupfunctions:
    f()
```