# Automatically call all functions matching a certain pattern in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the same intention as in this question:

[Automatically call all functions matching a certain pattern in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281300/automatically-call-all-functions-matching-a-certain-pattern-in-python)

But I needed the solution (if technically possible) in VB.NET. Is that possible in VB.NET ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can do that, that's what reflection is for:

```
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim methods = GetType(Module1).GetMethods() _
            .Where(Function(m) m.Name.StartsWith("Setup"))
        For Each method As MethodInfo In methods
            method.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub Setup1()
        Console.WriteLine(1)
    End Sub

    Sub Setup2()
        Console.WriteLine(2)
    End Sub

    Sub Setup3()
        Console.WriteLine(3)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: @svick, sorry I'm a newbie and I just tested your code and visual studio 2008 showed following error: Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.

Comment: @david, sorry, I forgot you can't continue line in VB just like in C#, see updated answer.

Comment: VB.NET 10 (introduced with VS 2010) supports implicit line continuation without using the `_` character.

Comment: @Cody Gray, many thanks ! That is new info for me. VB.NET is getting smarter.

Comment: @david: You're welcome. I suppose it's good to know... I still use the line continuation characters out of habit. VB.NET may be getting smarter, but I'm clearly not. :-) Also do keep in mind that while Reflection will certainly work for this, there is a performance penalty involved in invoking functions this way. It's not nearly as fast as a direct call to the function. That may be perfectly OK for your purposes, but it's certainly worth knowing about regardless.

Comment: @Cody Gray, thanks for reminder, you are so knowledgeable, perhaps you can venture in writing books for VB.NET :)