# Is there a way to import a group of functions from a namespace "as" something (without the *)?

Tags: python

Rather than defining

```
from numpy import cos as cos
from numpy import arccos as arccos
```

and so on, can I do something like

```
trigfunctions = ('cos','arccos','sin','arcsin','tan','arctan')
for method in trigfunctions:
    setattr(HERE,method,getattr(numpy,method))
```

Where `HERE` is either global space (or possibly, local function environment)? This would make it easier to define general functions based on `cos`, `arccos` without specifying the namespace, and loading the appropriate function from the desired module (e.g., `math` if `numpy` is not available). I realize that this can lead to errors when applied very generally, but in some small instances it would be useful.

Comment: Do you have a question?  If so, what is it?

Comment: It is '... can I do somthing like $CODE, where ...'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean [importing](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import-name1-name2) with the same name, simply leave off the `as`:

```
from numpy import cos, arccos, sin, arcsin, tan, arctan
```

Beyond that, you can use [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions#globals) to get the [symbol table for the current module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990422/how-to-get-a-reference-to-current-modules-attributes-in-python):

```
me=globals();
trigfunctions = ('cos','arccos','sin','arcsin','tan','arctan')
for method in trigfunctions:
    me[method] = numpy.__dict__[method]
```

You can also use [`sys.modules[__name__]`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys#sys.modules) to reference the current module.

Comment: But why `numpy.__dict__[method]` rather than `getattr(numpy,method)`?

Comment: No particular reason; it's just another way of doing the same thing a little more directly. Considering the comment regarding [module namespaces](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#id2) in the Python docs, `getattr` is probably the better of the two.

Comment: Thanks for your response -- yes, seems like getattr would be better in this case.