# How do you get a list of objects in a script so that you can print __doc__ on each of them?

Tags: python, docstring

In my script `test.py` I have a lot of functions and classes and then I have the following:

```
for i in dir():
    if i[0] != '_':
        print(type(i), i.__doc__)
```

But it doesnt work because when using `dir()` to get a list of what is in my namespace, I get a list of strings and not objects.
How can I print the docstrings of all the objects (that have docstrings) in my script?

**Solution based on Ashwini Chaudhary's answer**

I put this in my main() function after the module has been loaded:

```
# Print out all the documentation for all my functions and classes at once 
    for k, obj in sorted(globals().items()): #vars().items():
        if k[0] != '_' and hasattr(obj,'__doc__'):
#           if type(obj) != 'module' and type(obj) != 'str' and type(obj) != 'int':
                print(k, obj.__doc__)# == 'class': # or type(obj) == 'function'):
    sys.exit()
```

For some reason `if type(obj) != 'module'` is not respected so I couldnt use that as a filter to get only my own functions. But that is OK for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vars().items()`:

```
for k, obj in vars().items():
    if k[0] != '_':
       print(type(obj), obj.__doc__)
```

`help()` on `vars`:

```
vars(...)
    vars([object]) -> dictionary

    Without arguments, equivalent to locals().
    With an argument, equivalent to object.__dict__.
```

Comment: Calling `vars().items()` at the end of my script created a `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`, see above for what i did instead.

Comment: @PaulH You're trying to update a dictionary while iterating over it, what will raise an error. And it is not a good idea to update `vars()` and `globals()`.

Answer (score 1):

if `dir` is giving you the stuff you want, you can use `globals` to look up the objects themselves.

```
for i in dir():
    if i[0] != '_':
        item = globals()[i]
        print(type(item), item.__doc__)
```

If you want more fine control over what you get, you can use `inspect.getmembers`.  In order to get a reference to the current module, you need `sys` as documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/991158/748858).