# Create object type from a string

Tags: python, xml

The title may be very vague, I did not know how to put the problem, so please excuse me for this.

I have a python file, say **module.py**

```
class myClass(obj):
    """
    class Description
    """
    def myMethod(args):
        """
        method Description
        """
        # method definition
```

I have one xml file, say **module_result.xml**

```
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="module.myClass-20161215114804" skipped="0" tests="1" time="0.000">
    <testcase classname="module.myClass" name="myMethod" time="0.000"/>
    <system-out>
        something
    </system-out>
</testsuite>
```

I have another python file, **test.py** from where I have to use module_result.xml to parse module.py
What I am doing in test.py (by giving hard coded path) is:

```
getdoc(module.myClass.myMethod)
```

I have to make this generic by reading names from xml, and those names are of type *string*

The argument type for *getdoc()* is *object* type, I am getting this error while using getddoc() with string:

```
str(object='') -> str
str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str

Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer
that will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler.
Otherwise, returns the result of object.__str__() (if defined)
or repr(object).
encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
errors defaults to 'strict'.
```

working code in test.py:

```
import module
getdoc(module.myClass.myMethod)
```

But, this is hard coded, which is not acceptable in my case

I am extracting module/myClass/myMethod names from xml file

Lets say I got those names in variable by some logic as:

```
string_variable = "module.myClass.myMethod"
```

and I now want to do this:

```
getdoc(string_variable)
```

after doing this I am getting above mentioned error.

What can I do to convert string to object type?

Answer (score 2):

Referencing two different questions from elsewhere

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/python-dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990422/how-to-get-a-reference-to-current-modules-attributes-in-python)

Let's say you want to instantiate an instance of "myClass" from "myModule".  To keep it simple, let's assume that "myModule" is already imported

```
import sys
import myModule
import myOtherModule

def create_object(modulename, classname):   # modulename and classname are strings
    mod = sys.modules[modulename]
    cls = getattr(mod, classname)
    inst = cls()
    return inst
```

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to convey.. What is 'name' here?

Comment: I thought what you were asking was this: *given a string that represents the name of a class, how do I instantiate an instance of that class?*.  In any case, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/python-dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported) might we what you are looking for.

Comment: I updated my answer again to reflect some new stuff I learned.

Comment: You got the question right the first time.. here I don't know the name of module/class/method....   They are just stored in some variable or list as string type (which was extracted from the xml file).  I will edit the question to make things more clear...

Comment: My updated answer is close to what you want.  It assumes the module is already imported, but you have the target class in string form.  e.g. `obj = create_object("myModule", "myClass")`  You can use the links I reference on how to dynamically import a module by string e.g.`__import__("myModule")`