# Running command from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wanting to create a CLI that will accept input from the user and run commands based on what they input.

```
def apple():
    print("Apple")

def orange():
    print("Orange")

def grape():
    print("Grape")


userinput = input("Which function do you want to run? ")

userinput()
```

What I am trying to get to work is, when the user enters "Orange" it will print Orange. Same for apple and grape. My real project will incorporate a lot more functions the user can input but this is the part I am stuck on at the moment.

Comment: I am unclear as to what exactly you are asking.

Comment: `globals()[userinput]()`?

Comment: Combine [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3061/2988730) with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/990422/2988730) (mostly the second one), and you're good to go.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov. I'd go with `globals` since you're eventually going to want to stick that into a function, but same difference.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: sure, I've used `vars` because it was shorter and in given context will behave like `globals` (but `globals` obviously is a correct choice)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov. While we both know what to do, I still have no idea what OP is actually asking. There is a "want" and some requirements, and while those are spelled out clearly enough, there is no implied action on our part that isn't out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, here's how I would implement something like that:

```
class Commands:
    @staticmethod
    def _apple():
        print("Apple")

    @staticmethod
    def _orange():
        print("Orange")

    @staticmethod
    def _grape():
        print("Grape")

    def run(self, cmd_name):
        getattr(Commands, '_' + cmd_name.lower())()
```

You can then run it with `Commands.run(input())`

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was wanting. i was looking into the getattr command but I wasn't fully understanding it. This helps to understand.